# Ubuntu 16.04 LTE Beta2 - failed to resume after suspend

Tags: compiz, suspend, 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTE Beta2 and I have strange problem. System is quite stable but I'm unable to resume after suspend my Dell E6420. When I suspend (manually or by closing lid) laptop turning to full load, fan is 100% and screen getting black. Laptop is working normally, keyboard is highlighted, disk and WiFi working, I can connect via SSH.

What I tried:
- it doesn't matter if it's clean 16.04 or upgraded from 15.10, same thing happens
- tried to upgrade kernel - now its running on 4.5RC1 (btw works even better than 4.4 LTS)
- the thing causing high CPU load is compiz (70% CPU usage) and Xorg (25% CPU usage). Checked using TOP command.

Any tips what should I do? I'm new in linux so I will rly appreciate any kind of help and sorry for my english :).

Thanks,
Edek_5

Comment: Beta versions are off-topic at this site. Report a bug.

Comment: I'm sorry , I didnt know. So where should I ask?

Comment: You should not "ask" but report issues with beta versions to launchpad.

Comment: By 'Beta version' @Pilot6 means it is not the stable final version. You can try and report the issue or wait till the stable version of 16.04 is released.

Comment: As I mention I'm new with linux so I didnt know about that. I'm now on 16.04 and maybe someone can find a workaround for that. Cause system normally works, but compiz is creazy. So maybe restart compiz + something to bring it back? I'm just curious :)

But ok, I will try to find a way how to report this on Launchpad ;) Thx anyway.

Comment: Bug still exists. Here is Launchpad description: [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1574142)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. There is apparently a bug in the 4.4.0 kernel. The problem can be solved when you install the new kernel 4.4.8.

You can find instructions to do it here: http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I have reported problem as bug, its confirmed. Now I'm on 4.5 kernel and bug still exists.  I will check 4.4.8 kernel on fresh installation tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah the bug will probably get fixed in an update. I just posted this in case you were impatient like me :-)

Comment: I'm not impatient but its kind a frustrating bug. But i followed this idea to check more kernels and results are like below. On 4.4.8 works suspension but is a problem with WiFi.  Best choice for now is 4.5.1 :) Thx for solution, cant give you a point but thx :) 
![Checked kernels](http://i.imgur.com/iBAShOK.png)